# Constructing object types based on logic - can this be done?

Tags: java, object, subclass, abstract

I'm hoping that someone can steer me in the right direction. I can't seem to find a proper solution to this issue anywhere.

I have an **abstract** class called *`Student`*. Three external classes extend Student. These are called `Graduate`, `Undergraduate`, and `PartTime`. In my main method, I would like to construct an object as either Graduate, Undergraduate, or PartTime based on some logic. For example:

```
if (something) { Graduate student = new Graduate(); }
else if (something { Undergraduate student = new Undergraduate(); }
```

If I try this, the compiler (I'm using Netbeans) complains that object student has already been defined. If I try this:

```
Student student;
if (something) { student = new Graduate(); }
```

student is unable to access any of the methods specific to Graduate.

Would anything change if I were to make the three extended classes inner static classes of Student?

Hopefully the issue is clear. Any suggestions about how I could solve this problem? Any suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
Student student;
if (something) {
  Graduate graduate = new Graduate();
  graduate.visitMissisRobinson( );

  student = graduate;
}
else if (somethingElse) {
  Undergraduate undegradStudent = new Undergraduate();

  undegradStudent.declareMajor( );

  student = undegradStudent;
}

// now only do common methods of student
student.chargeTuition( );
```

Comment: You could also use explicit casts, but this is definitely cleaner.

Comment: I didn't think of using an intermediate. Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't work:
if (something) {
Graduate graduate = new Graduate();
student = graduate;
}

As soon as I try to call a method specific to Graduate, the compiler asks me if it should create the method under Student. Any idea why this would be?

Answer (score 0):

If you want some more in depth reading regarding the subject look for some factory pattern :

[Factory pattern](http://www.allapplabs.com/java_design_patterns/factory_pattern.htm)